# How Do I install the Nagios check_snmp Plugin?

Tags: nagios3

I have installed Nagios in my ec2 server. Now I want to install `check_snmp` plugin. I found that this is not available in :

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

I tried :

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins-snmp
```

But I'm getting :

```
E: Unable to locate package nagios-plugins-snmp
```

How can I install the plugins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is in the `nagios-plugins-standard` package. I'd suggest installing the `nagios-plugins` package, as that will install it, as well as the `nagios-plugins-basic` package:

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

Then, your SNMP plugin will be available in:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp
```

Comment: +1 for the answer...If I do that, I'm getting this : 
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.`

Comment: So you already have the `check_snmp` plugin then? Can you not find it at `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/`?

Comment: Actually I use `nagios3` version. There is nothing in `/usr/lib/nagios3/`. I need to install plugin for `nagios3` and not in `nagios` (which is also installed in my system). Is there any way I can configure my `nagios3` to take up plugins from `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/` in `nagios.cfg` file?

Answer (score 2):

On your monitoring server:

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

All standarded plugins will be installed in

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

Not in

```
/usr/lib/nagios3/
```

Please see [Nagios - Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/nagios.html) in the section of "Configuration Overview"

Then in

```
/etc/nagios-plugins/config/
```

you will find snap.cfg, which assigns each command_line a correspondent command_name.

For example

```
define command{
    command_name    snmp_load
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -C '$ARG1$' -o .$
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and found the problem.

The point is that when you have installed the `nagios-plugins`, you shouldn't had `net-snmp` and `net-snmp-utils` packages installed at all. And thats why `check_snmp` were not compiled.

For fix this, you have to install `net-snmp` and `net-snmp-utils` and after that compile/install `nagios-plugins` again.

FYI: copy paste from another forum
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

If you install nagios 4 following [this tutorial](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/08/install-and-configure-nagios-core-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/), then your installation directory is `/usr/local/nagios`.

On starting nagios and browsing to nagios admin portal, you could see the following errors

```
 - (No output on stdout) stderr:
   execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping
 - (No output on stdout) stderr:
   execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users
 - (No output on stdout) stderr:
   execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http
```

This is how I fixed the above errors,
Install plugins

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

This will install all plugins to `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins` directory.

Just copy all files starting with `check_*` to `/usr/local/nginx/libexec`.

```
cp /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_* /usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

and wait for nagios to reload/refresh browser window